# Connecting Oracle Fusion Application with DocuSign API

Tags: oracle, docusignapi

I am looking for some help setting up a connection between Oracle Fusion and DocuSign API. We want to use DocuSign to electronically sign procurement contracts we have in Oracle Fusion Procurement application and to set this up you need to provide the following details onto a form in Oracle Fusion:
Username
Password
Account ID
EndPoint URL
Once this is entered, you can click 'Validate' and the form will validate the connection for you.

I got most of this information from the API section of my demo account so have been able to provide everything except the EndPoint URL. To fibnd this out, I used the API explorer tool http://iodocs.docusign.com/, entered my account details at the top of the form and ran the GET v2/login_information REST message. The response I retrieved contained a 'baseURL' which I assumed was the same as the EndPoint URL and input this into the Oracle Fusion form, hit validate but unfortunately I was still unable to validate the connection.

I spoke with Oracle support and they advised that from their side they simply need the information in the form to validate the connection (assuming that information is correct and a DocuSign account exists) there doesn't appear to be anything else required to make a connection. So I can only assume that something isn't configured correctly within my DocuSign demo account and need some advice on how to check this. If anyone has had to do this in the past and came up against the same issue I'd love to know how you managed to get it working.

Any help and suggestions would be greatly appreciated :-)

Thanks,
Jamie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on that information, my guess is that the "EndPoint URL" would actually be something like https://demo.docusign.net.  The application can then append whatever it needs after that.  You could also try these:

- demo.docusign.net
- https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2
- https://demo.docusign.net/API/3.0/api.asmx
- https://demo.docusign.net/API/3.0/dsapi.asmx

(Note:  The last two are for the SOAP API.)

Comment: Thank you (knew would be a simple one) The top URL seemed to work, I just had to add 'https://' to the start of it. Thanks